# Deploying a Rails App. and user installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm working on a blogging system and I'm just wondering if there's an easy way for someone to deploy it there server and configure the installation.

What I mean by that is to allow them to select the database name, user and password as well as creating an admin account. Much like how Wordpress does it.

Comment: you should probably use Heroku. Very minimal configuration and no dev-ops skills needed. But are you trying to distribute your app or just get it running?

Comment: I'm hoping to put it on github for others to download and use.

Comment: well, go ahead and put it on github. Then create an account on Heroku, and follow the instructions on how to deploy it here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

Comment: If you want to have a UI config page like WordPress you probably will need to [configure your controller to call task](http://railscasts.com/episodes/127-rake-in-background).